# Singularities of fibrations in conics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-geometry, singularity-theory, conic-bundles

Consider a rank two vector bundle $E = \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)\oplus \mathcal{O}(c)$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$. Fix coordinates $u_0,u_1$ on the base $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $v_0,v_1,v_2$ on the fibers of $\mathbb{P}(E)$, and let $F$ be an irreducible polynomial in $u_0,u_1,v_0,v_1,v_2$ which is homogeneous of degree two in $v_0,v_1,v_2$.

Then a fiber of the projection $X = (F = 0)\subset\mathbb{P}(E)\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ is either a smooth conic or the union of two lines or a double line.

In this setting is it true that $X$ has at most Du Val singularities?

Answer (score 4):

It might be that $X$ is singular along some fiber that is a double line. To arrange this, start with $Y \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ with such a fiber over the point $P$ and then pull back by a double cover $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ that is branched over $P$. Otherwise you are right: a surface singularity with a section that is nodal is necessarily du Val, of type $A$.